# Startup.cs security measures

Tags: c#, web-hosting, asp.net-core-2.0

I would like to know whether I am
(a) engaging in good coding practices,
(b) repeating myself harmlessly, or
(c) adding inefficient redundancies

For example:
1) In Configure() I can add `RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttps();`
2) In ConfigureServices() I can add
 `services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
            { options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute()); });`

Another example:
1) In Configure() I can add `app.UseAuthentication();`
2) In ConfigureServices() I can add `.RequireAuthenticatedUser()` to my `AddMvc()` call.

It *seems* in both examples that I can get away with just one call. Am I free and clear to keep only one call? And if so, which one is the better to keep?

I've searched around a fair bit and I can see all of these approaches in use, but I haven't found a resource that compares the relative merits of these calls, let alone indicates whether it's good or bad practice to use them together.

Comment: This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl) should provide enough information for the first query.

Comment: Ah, so one redirects, and the other refuses? So it wouldn't make sense to keep both, but I would need to decide if I want to redirect or rather just refuse the request entirely? That's a helpful link!. If I read this page before, I certainly didn't pick up on the difference. I find myself asking this next question... if it's best practice to RequireHttpsAttribute... but I don't want to turn traffic away, does the redirect happen before or after the refusal of http requests? I will research this, but insights welcome here!

Comment: That link is actually confusing - _both_ of those options redirect to HTTPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take your first example:

> 1) In `Configure()` I can add `RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttps()`;
>
> 2) In `ConfigureServices()` I can add  `services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
>              { options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute()); });`

Both of these achieve essentially the same thing - they will redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS. The difference is which requests they are applied to.

If you use the rewriter middleware, all requests that make it to the middleware will be redirected to HTTPS.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles(); // Requests handled by this middleware won't be redirected to HTTPS

    var options = new RewriteOptions()
       .AddRedirectToHttps();

    app.UseRewriter(options); // All requests that make it this far will be redirected from HTTP to HTTPS

    app.UseMvc(); // Requests guaranteed to be HTTPS
}
```

In the second case, where you use a global filter to apply the `RequireHttpsAttribute`, only requests that make it to the `MvcMiddleware` will be redirected to HTTPS.

In terms of best practices, I recommend using the rewriter middleware - you can add it to the start of your middleware pipeline, and then all of your requests are required to HTTPS, instead of just the requests that make it to the MVC middleware.

---

In your second example, the two methods actually do different things:

- `app.UseAuthentication()` - authenticates the request, and sets the `User` associated with the request by e.g. deserializing the user principal stored in the cookie
- `RequireAuthenticatedUser()` - Requires that a User has logged in before action methods on your controllers are called. If the user hasn't logged in, they are redirected to the login page. In this case, you *must* call `app.UseAuthentication()` before `app.UseMvc()`, otherwise the `User` for the request will not be set even if you've logged in, and you will be redirected to the login page.

Comment: I will be scrutinizing this one for a good while. Thanks Sock!